# SheetJs converting string with date automatically to date angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, xlsx, sheetjs

I am importing a CSV file in my angular application using sheetjs, Data is imported successfully. but it is converting string with a date to only date ignoring the string.

[image]

[image]

Code in ts file

```
readExcel() {
    let readFile = new FileReader();
    readFile.onload = (e) => {
        this.storeData = readFile.result;
        var data = new Uint8Array(this.storeData);
        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        var bstr = arr.join("");
        var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" });
        var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        this.worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

        let processJsonData: Array<any> = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.worksheet, { raw: false });
        console.log(processJsonData)
    }
}
```

How to get both string and date in the json response. Please suggest

Comment: means, inside your csv file you have date field as string, and when you starts to convert using sheetjs then string-date field gets converted to date format, and final you get only date format ?

Comment: @GRD Yes I am getting only date value ignoring date field